# Java explode by space

Tags: java

I have a function

```
if (text.startsWith("item")) {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 1;
            int id = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(7));
            int amount = ???
            Stream.createFrame(x);
            Stream.writeDWord(y);
            Stream.writeDWord(id); //itemid
            Stream.writeDWord(10000); //amount
}
```

it should add an item to inventory, id can be 1 to 6 characters long, i need to explode that amount integer from string, how do i do that in this case? I hope you guys understand what i am asking for, i am a caveman in java..

Comment: Can you explain " i need to explode that amount integer from string"

Comment: No, we don't understand. If you can't explain by words then give some sample input and corresponding outputs

Comment: Sorry I am confused by myself. Well I should use this function from input ingame, lets say I write "item 55 300" and it
should add item with id 55 and amount 300..

So I just want to explode that text from input, I get item id by 
  int id = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(7)); but basically everything after word item becomes item id.. so I want to split 
  that "everything" by space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String testString = "item 456 234";
String[] elements = testString.split(" ");
int id = Integer.parseInt(elements[1]);
int amount = Integer.parseInt(elements[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
String[] array = test.split("\\s+");
if (array.length != 3)
{
//report invalid data format
}
else
{
int id = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
int amount = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
}
```